How to print expressions which satisfied the parse rule i defined?
I'm new to antlr4. In "The Definitive ANTLR4 Reference", I know how to print token during parse. But I have a request to print the expression which satisfied the parse rule. I have no idea for this.
This is an example of an expression I want to parse: a=5 & b=6 & c=7
I want to print 3 propositions like:
p1:`a=5`,
p2:`b=6`,
p3:`c=7`

separately, but antlr4 seems to only support print like a or 5 (tokens in parse tree), that lose the structure of expression.
Please help me how to do this.
there is a part of my grammar rule:
propos: expr op=('&' | '|' | '->') expr;
expr: VAR | VALUE;
VAR: [a-zA-Z]+;
VALUE: [0-9]+;

I follow the method in manual to modify my grammar file:
propos: (expr op=('&' | '|' | '->') expr     //# PRINT_NO_QUAN_PROPOS //no-quantifier proposition
   {
    System.out.println($propos.getText());
   }
)

but when I compile this file, it gives me error message cannot find propos  System.out.println($propos.getText());

What if you remove $propos.? So just:  System.out.println(getText());

@BartKiers Thanks for your reply, but it still gives me the same error.
”contractParser.java:291: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println(getText());
^
symbol:   method getText()
location: class contractParser
1 error“

That is not the same error though…

This seems to work:
propos: expr op=('&' | '|' | '->') expr {System.out.println(this.getContext().getText());};

However, it is bad practice to add target specific code to your grammar. Try using a listener instead. Given your grammar:
grammar T;

propos: expr op=('&' | '|' | '->') expr;
expr: VAR | VALUE;
VAR: [a-zA-Z]+;
VALUE: [0-9]+;

and then running the code:
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker;

public class ListenerDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TLexer lexer = new TLexer(CharStreams.fromString("a&b"));
        TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new DemoListener(), parser.propos());
    }
}

class DemoListener extends TBaseListener {
    @Override
    public void enterPropos(TParser.ProposContext ctx) {
        System.out.printf("propos: %s%n", ctx.getText());
    }
}

will print:
propos: a&b


This works for me.Thanks! But I need more reputation to vote  :)
